# How change required comment messages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How i make change required message to any text ?

```
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

    $fields =  array(
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' ></div>',

);
```

Comment: What is the value of $req in this context?

Comment: @randomtu i edit quession, $req variable where saved values required email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need these parenthesis.

```
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
```

Replace it with:

```
$aria_req = $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '';
```

If $req has a value, render the aria attribute. And I don't think you need the $fields variable to be an array too, unless you're doing something else with it.

```
$fields = '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' ></div>';
```